# Passing multiple arguments to a macro?

Tags: craft3, macro, params

I have a link on a website that i'd like to set a class of active on, based on different segments.

```
{% macro is_acitve(segment) %}
    {% if craft.app.request.getSegment(2) == segment %}active{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

```
<a href="/the-url" class="{{ macros.is_active('test1', 'test2', 'test3') }}">Link Title</a>
```

It's not working. How would I go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off sending the values as an array, then you will only need one parameter.

```
{# Change the macro to check for the value in an array #}
{% macro is_active(segments) %}
    {% if craft.app.request.getSegment(2) in segments %}active{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

```
{# Send an array to the macro #}
<a href="/the-url" class="{{ macros.is_active(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']) }}">Link Title</a>
```